# Jaxb unmarshal doesn't works

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
        <Result diffgr:id="Result1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <CITY>York</CITY>
        </Result>
    </DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I have this java code:

```
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

        String content = readFile("D:\\work\\cim\\target\\my.xml", Charset.defaultCharset());    

        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new StringReader(content));    

        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag();
        while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("Result")) {
            xsr.nextTag();
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CimRecordTest.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<CimRecordTest> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, CimRecordTest.class);
        xsr.close();

        CimRecordTest cimRecordTest = jb.getValue();
        System.out.println(cimRecordTest.getCity());
```

In console output I see `null`

What do I wrong?

**P.S**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CimRecordTest {
    /**
     * CITY
     */
   @XmlElement(name="CITY")
    private String city;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

P.S I make according http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html - I don't see differences

**P.S.**

java version "1.7.0_45"

Comment: Works and prints `York` for me. Are you sure that's what you got?

Comment: at my home pc - too. But at work doesn't work

Comment: What Java version are both running?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that they have something different between them and you just haven't noticed it. I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Now I am at work. and all code copyed from work pc

Comment: Exist resource where I can compile and execute this code?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis can you share your project for me? I want to launch your project.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I investigated problem and got some results.

Comment: not valid == null instead of York

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is jaxb version problem.

after adding this content to POM.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

this problem is disappeared

I investigated  problem and I confused.

I have 2 projects - project1 and project2. I noticed that

**for project1 valid**

```
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.7</version>
            </dependency>
```

and

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**But for project2 valid only**

```
                dependency>
                   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.7</version>
                </dependency>
```

I am very confused and messed. But I want to know true about this problem.