# jaxb Enum to string custom mapping

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have enum

```
public enum CimRecordType {
    Account, ShippingAddress
}
```

and java bean

```
public class MyClass{
   @XmlElement(name= "RECORD_TYPE",required = true)
   public CimRecordType rt;
}
```

and my xml:

```
<Result >
        <RECORD_TYPE>ACCNT</RECORD_TYPE>
</Result>
```

Account!=ACCNT

But I want to

1. map ACCNT as Account when I would unmarshal xml.
2. map Account as ACCNT when I would marshal xml.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlEnumValue` annotation for this.

Comment: simple example expose  here

Comment: what about marshalling enum -> xml ?

Comment: awesome. I glad to have conversation with jaxb creator. I want to know your opinion about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191021/jaxb-unmarshal-doesnt-works/22196764#22196764

Comment: @gstackoverflow - I was part of the expert group (JSR-222) that created JAXB and the lead of the EclipseLink MOXy implementation of it.  I will take a look at the question you linked to.